# Buenas Practicas, Detalle de Usuario, sin usuarios

Tags: laravel

tengo un problema de planteamiento para comenzar un proyecto... estoy por armar un sistema en laravel, el cual tiene 2 sectores.

En la parte administrativa, tengo un control de clientes, los cuales pueden estar o no registrados como "usuarios" en el sistema... y aquí es donde viene mi duda.

Yo en el sistema de servicio técnico y ventas, agrego un cliente con sus datos personales y le asigno equipos o ventas... pero deseo que el cliente luego pueda ir a la web y registrarse con su email, contraseña y numero de documento... al iniciar sesión aparezcan sus equipos sus services y sus compras anteriores ya asignadas.

Alguien podría darme una idea como hacer esto?

Yo tenia en mente hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

Tabla Users (donde se guardan el email y contraseña y el nombre reemplazarlo por el DNI de la persona..)

Crear otra tabla llamada UserDetails donde se guarden... DNI nuevamente, nombre y apellido, FechaNacimiento, direccion, notas.

luego por ejemplo, en la boletas y remitos de servicio técnico se enlacen por medio del DNI de UserDetails en el background... y en el front-end que los clientes filtren los datos buscando el numero de dni de su cuenta en el UserDetails.

Esta bien esto? o se puede hacer de otra manera?

Answer (score 1):

Personalmente no lo enlazaría, imagina la posibilidad de que alguien más se haga con tus boletas, entonces se lo asignaría, lo que haría sería a grandes rasgos crear la tabla de clientes, la tabla de detalles de cliente, y la tabla de recibos/boletas, donde ahora sí, mediante FK clientes↔detalles_cliente mediante un ID, y la tabla recibos, donde tendría una columna que sería para guardar el ID del cliente en dicho caso de que ese cliente decidiera registrarse, entonces esa boleta se le asignaría a ese ID de cliente, de tal forma que no podrían repetirse.

Imagina el caso que ocurre con amazon, las compras las haces con tu nombre, pero, el pago puede ser con la tarjeta de alguien más, entonces, es una relación de uno a muchos, donde un cliente puede tener muchas tarjetas de diferentes personas, pero, la compra es únicamente de la persona de la cuenta de amazon, no sé si me di a entender, en dado caso:

- Yo compro por ejemplo un balón en amazon
- Se me asigna el balón a mi usuario
- Mi balón ya no lo puede tener nadie más, pueden haber más
  balones, pero no el mío

Comment: Hola!! gracias por tu respuesta, considera mirar el [tour] y tambien [answer]. La pregunta fue cerrada porque esta totalmente basada en opiniones... asi como vos tenes esta opinion, otra persona puede tener otra, y no es la funcionalidad del sitio discutir...

Comment: Hola, ha respondido correctamente la pregunta era para que me dieran una opinión para poder basarme!

Comment: Gracias Victor, despejarte mí enredo, es exactamente lo que tenía en mente pero me hice lío y no supe explicar mí punto correctamente, mil gracias!